# how to compile mclinker in android source (AOSP)?

Tags: android, llvm, android-source

Does anyone known how to compile 'mclinker' in android source (AOSP)?
when i use 'make frameworks/compile/mclinker/' or 'mmma frameworks/compile/mclinker/'，
it show me the result "make: Nothing to be done for `frameworks/compile/mclinker/'"。

Comment: Does the folder contain a `Android.bp` or `Android.mk`?

Answer (score 0):

[frameworks/compile/mclinker](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/compile/mclinker/+/refs/heads/android10-release/) has multiple targets defined. You likely want to build the `ld.mc` binary ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/compile/mclinker/+/refs/heads/android10-release/tools/mcld/Android.bp#26)).

You can run `m` with any module as target.

```
m ld.mc
```